# exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation lazyinitializer mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build asp.net mvc4 application and while running the application, I am getting the error `Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation` on the statement of lazyinitializer. Please help. Thanks in advance. My code is as follows

```
namespace CMMIS.Web.Filters
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

its because the LazyInitializer is being mimicked in the webconfig.just remove it the code will run fine